# Failing to verify ECDSA signture using ecsda package

Tags: go, cryptography, ecdsa

I have generated a signture and base64 encoded it:

`4d4559434951436c627834634e4b4d513944764d2f4d4f536c3636642f344f4f4c74777a48493661676e427a4149395838514968414c37683959464e575242784e56497675706b534b3362564b735049717a445067464e5a563164415a506565`

Using public key:
`MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEzIeFzpGyGzsHi66o07Hlzkv7T92dbSvDh5UIerOJl7l93RCc8VnvSm6MhuvKb4snojkUEMq0gDVb4fHlzSfzWw==`

When I hash the same message and try to verify it, it fails.

I am using the package `crypto/ecsda` in Go and the functions `SignASN1` and `VerifyASN1` from the package.

I have written 2 programs, one to sign and the other to verify in the go playground and it fails to verify, what could be the problem?

program to sign :https://play.golang.org/p/D8KLUrEelRI

program to verify : https://play.golang.org/p/R7ZUBnvCJ0o

Note: functions are available in go version 15 and above.

program code to sign

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/base64"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/sha256"
)

func main() {
        prik ,ee := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("MHcCAQEEIOjE1zQtdzs10msOj4JuX6URIDJOVg5AaR8wCtEM227ZoAoGCCqGSM49AwEHoUQDQgAEzIeFzpGyGzsHi66o07Hlzkv7T92dbSvDh5UIerOJl7l93RCc8VnvSm6MhuvKb4snojkUEMq0gDVb4fHlzSfzWw==")
        if ee != nil{
        panic(ee)
        }
        
        privateKey, e := x509.ParseECPrivateKey(prik)
        if e != nil{
        panic(e)
        }
        

    msg := "6e80bec4-1"
    hash := sha256.Sum256([]byte(msg))
    sig, err := ecdsa.SignASN1(rand.Reader, privateKey, hash[:])
    
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("signature: %x\n", base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(sig))

    
    
    
    
       
}
```

Program to verify the signature.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/base64"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/sha256"
)

func main() {
    pubkdata, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEzIeFzpGyGzsHi66o07Hlzkv7T92dbSvDh5UIerOJl7l93RCc8VnvSm6MhuvKb4snojkUEMq0gDVb4fHlzSfzWw==")
    sig, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("4d4559434951436c627834634e4b4d513944764d2f4d4f536c3636642f344f4f4c74777a48493661676e427a4149395838514968414c37683959464e575242784e56497675706b534b3362564b735049717a445067464e5a563164415a506565")
    PK, _:= x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(pubkdata)
    //Validate the signture
    
    msg := "6e80bec4-1"
    hash := sha256.Sum256([]byte(msg))
    valid := ecdsa.VerifyASN1(PK.(*ecdsa.PublicKey), hash[:], sig)
    fmt.Println("signature verified:", valid)
}
```

Result: `signature verified: false`

Comment: Please include all the relevant code into the question.

Comment: @bereal I have included links to the code so that it can be run in the play ground, which other code would you like me to include?

Comment: Relevant code must be directly in the question (playground links are welcome, but they shouldn't be the only thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing out the signature's base64 using hexadecimal representation:

```
fmt.Printf("signature: %x\n", base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(sig))
```

Afterwards you try to parse the output as if it was base64, that's why you're getting a different result. Replace the print format with `%s`, and it should work:

```
fmt.Printf("signature: %s\n", base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(sig))
```